# Портфолио для фрилансера

Tags: работа

Здравствуйте!

Допустим, я захотел позаниматься фрилансом. Везде слышал, что для фрилансера нужно портфолио.

Скажите, пожалуйста (особенно те, кто этим зарабатывает), что должно содержать портфолио? (Для примера портфолио веб-разработчика или портфолио разработчика под мобильные платформы.) Подойдет ли для портфолио список проектов на гитхабе? Или лучше какой-то готовый продукт, например, сайт? Интересен ли заказчику сам код или лучше показывать конечный продукт?

Что делать, если, скажем, весь код, который не стыдно показывать, находится в собственности работодателя, и его нельзя просто так выложить и показать? Много ли проектов должно быть в портфолио?

В общем, что обычно бывает в этом портфолио?  Заранее всем спасибо!

Answer (score 4):

Заказчиками на фрилансе выступают обычные люди, которым, как правило, дела нет до того, что у Вас там в коде творится и что это вообще такое. Однако они хотят знать, кого нанимают и что в итоге из этого выйдет. Как правило, им важен только работающий результат, цена и время. Для облегчения этой задачи на фрилансе действует "рейтинг" и "портфолио". В портфолио, как правило, добавляются конечные продукты, которые они могут посмотреть или пощупать. Чем функциональнее и красивее продукт, тем больше шанс, что он понравится заказчику и он выберет Вас.

Количество проектов в портфолио зависит от того, как много вы хотите показать потенциальному работодателю. Не слишком много, так как он не дойдет до конца, скорее всего, и не слишком мало. Если сервис позволяет, то лучше работы разбивать на группы по категориям, которые будут понятны простым людям с поверхностным понимаем области, в которой вы хотите фрилансить. Конечно, Вам могут попасться и знающие люди, на них тоже можно рассчитывать, но их меньшинство.

В общем, тут работает принцип красивой обертки.

Comment: хорошо, код не нужен. Так а что же показывать тогда? Какие именно конечные продукты? Скажем, я начинающий программист и хочу подработать фрилансом. Что я могу показать в качестве портфолио?

Answer (score 1):

Мне кажется, ответ очевиден, в вашем портфолио должны быть ваши лучшие работы. У студента должен быть, наверное, как минимум дипломный проект. Плюс наверняка стажировки были? 
Если мобильный разработчик, то это приложения в appStore, windows store или google play.
Веб-девелопер - ваши сайты.

P.S. На фрилансе, мне кажется, много не заработаешь. Плюс риски.